# Sorting User Controls by dependency Property value

Tags: c#, sorting, date

I created a **usercontrol** that has 4 parameter Name/Date/Text/Color

- Here's My Date Value :

C#:

```
     public static readonly DependencyProperty _date
= DependencyProperty.Register(
"_date_value",
typeof(string),
typeof(date_ctrl),
new PropertyMetadata(null)
);
    public string _date_value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(_date); }
        set { SetValue(_date, value); }
    }
```

I'm adding my user control into a **stackpanel** children by code .

Now I want to sort this controllers , I know how to sort arrays and sort listbox items but How can I sort my stackpanel children by a specific property on usercontrols like **Date** ?

For Example :

**Stack Panel Children :**

- Usercontrol1 > Date Property > Value > 10/5/2019 10:30 AM
- Usercontrol2 > Date Property > Value > 9/1/2019 12:11 AM
- Usercontrol3 > Date Property > Value > 11/5/2020 08:08 PM
- Usercontrol4 > Date Property > Value > 2/12/2018 01:51 AM

**Sort by Date Values to :**

- Usercontrol4 > Date Property > Value > 2/12/2018 01:51 AM
- Usercontrol2 > Date Property > Value > 9/1/2019 12:11 AM
- Usercontrol1 > Date Property > Value > 10/5/2019 10:30 AM
- Usercontrol3 > Date Property > Value > 11/5/2020 08:08 PM

> Date Format : dd/mm/yy

Answer (score 1):

A StackPanel is just a list of controls. You cannot sort it. What you can do is store your controls in a List or Array and sort that, then bind it to the StackPanel.

1. Store the controls in a List or Dictionary
2. Sort the List or Dictionary
3. Remove controls from stackpanel using :
   StackPanel.Children.Remove(child)
4. Foreach member of List or
   Dictionary add controls to StackPanel using :
   StackPanel.Children.Insert(i, child);

Ideally you should use a ListBox/ItemsControl and use a CollectionViewSorce/SortDescription object to get this done. If you can you should be following a MVVM development approach. This makes the control binding and sorting much easier. See this post for a more complete answer of a similar question: [sorting elements in a stackpanel WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373343/sorting-elements-in-a-stackpanel-wpf)

Comment: thank you but I need to sort them by another data like dates , names not the main object.

Comment: I see you have edited your question quite a bit from your original. Even if you are using another control to determine the property to sort by you will have to remove the items from the stack panel and re add them.

Comment: To sort your user control list you could do something like ‘list.Sort( (c1,c2)=>c1.Date.CompareTo(c2.Date) );’

Comment: no I didn't :-? , thanks about the second example but what is c1 and c2 ? are they usercontrols ? If you need I can post project codes.

Comment: c1 and c2 are just the parameters for the sort function. The variable list in the example would just be your list of user controls. ‘List<YourUserControlType> list’